# Google Tag Manager Custom Events Capture Specific Page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm tracking multiple domains/subdomains (domain1.com, domain2.com and sub.domain1.com) with Google Tag Manager/universal analytics.

I created a Custom Tag Event (in GTM) that fires on ALL of those pages.

**Is there a way to capture the specific page where that event was fired from?**

For example, I have an event that fires when a user hovers over a specific `<div>` element. This occurs on both `domain1.com`, `domain2.com` and `sub.domain1.com`.

When those events fire, can I send the specific domain to GA's event catogory/action/label tags?

Answer (score 1):

some suggestions:

1) You should already be able to break down an event dimension by pages or visa versa (e.g. go to the event report and add pages as 2ndary dimension. Or go to the page you want to see and put event category/action/label as 2ndary dimension). You could also create a segment based on page name.  Of course, using the page names may not be useful if you are getting the default relative url (no domain). It is common for people to create a filter that adds domain prefix when spanning multiple domains.

2) Set a custom variable to pop with the domain (or full page name) during the event (or just set it when the visitor goes to the domain and set it as session/visit scope). You can then use this as a breakdown dimension. Or, you can use it to create a segment.

3) Restructure the event hierarchy to incorporate the domain. For example, make the top level (category) be the domain (or full page name).  I only suggest this as something you **can** do but ideally you should go with #1 or #2